# What is Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread for?

Tags: multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like someone to explain to me what is Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread and what is it for?

And also some examples of cases where it's used.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/System.Action/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just to add an example.

Imagine you have an async method `DoAnyWorkAsync` if you call it (just as an example) this way:

```
 DoAnyWorkAsync().ContinueWith ((arg) => {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Async operation completed...";
            });
```

`StatusLabel` is a label you have in the XAML.

The code above will not show the message in the label once the async operation had finished, because the callback is in another thread different than the UI thread and because of that it cannot modify the UI.

If the same code you update it a bit, just enclosing the `StatusLabel` text update within `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` like this:

```
 DoAnyWorkAsync().ContinueWith ((arg) => {
     Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Async operation completed...";
           });
     });
```

there will not be any problem.

Try it yourself, replacing `DoAnyWorkAsync()` with `Task.Delay(2000)`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 19):

**The simple answer is:** Background thread cannot modify UI elements because most UI operations in iOS and Android are not thread-safe; therefore, you need to invoke UI thread to execute the code that modifies UI such MyLabel.Text="New Text".

**The detailed answer** can be found in Xamarin document:

For iOS:

IOSPlatformServices.BeginInvokeOnMainThread() Method simply calls NSRunLoop.Main.BeginInvokeOnMainThread

```
public void BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action action)
{
    NSRunLoop.Main.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(action.Invoke);
}
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Foundation.NSObject.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/ObjCRuntime.Selector/Foundation.NSObject/

> You use this method from a thread to invoke the code in the specified object that is exposed with the specified selector in the UI thread. **This is required for most operations that affect UIKit or AppKit as neither one of those APIs is thread safe.**
>
> The code is executed when the main thread goes back to its main loop for processing events.

For Android:

Many People think on Xamarin.Android BeginInvokeOnMainThread() method use Activity.runOnUiThread(), BUT this is NOT the case, and there is a difference between using runOnUiThread() and Handler.Post():

```
public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {
    if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
        mHandler.post(action);//<-- post message delays action until UI thread is scheduled to handle messages
    } else {
        action.run();//<--action is executed immediately if current running thread is UI thread. 
    }
}
```

The actual implementation of Xamarin.Android BeginInvokeOnMainThread() method can be found in AndroidPlatformServices.cs class

```
public void BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action action)
{
    if (s_handler == null || s_handler.Looper != Looper.MainLooper)
    {
        s_handler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);
    }

    s_handler.Post(action);
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)
As you can see, you action code is not executed immediately by Handler.Post(action). It is added to the Looper's message queue, and is handled when the UI thread's scheduled to handle its message.

Comment: Just want to point out in the time since this was posted the new location of the android implementation is [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/79cc0f49fe90a59f02aa0490072b449ccdad4a27/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Forms.cs#L637)

and to find the other platform implementations search for `IPlatformServices` under the github repo

Answer (score 15):

You can only update the UI from the main UI thread.  If you are running code on a background thread and need to update the UI, `BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` allows you to force your code to run on the main thread, so you can update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

As explained above, any UI updates must happen in the main thread or an exception will occur.

Though there's a peculiarity with Xamarin.Forms, one can manilpulate UI elements (e.g. create `Label`s and add them to `StackLayout`'s `Children` collection) off the main thread without any failures as long as this part of UI is detached from UI elements currently displayed. This approach can be used to boost performance by creating Xamarin.Forms controls and setting their child/parent relations in-memory/off-screen in a separate thread BUT in order to attach them to displayed container (e.g. assign `ContentPage`'s `Content` property) you will have to do this in `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()`.

Answer (score 1):

While analysing the relationship between UI thread and background thread in some situation, we should be aware of the following:

`BeginInvokeOnMainThread` method as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/foundation.nsobject.begininvokeonmainthread), merely queues the invocation and **returns immediately** to the caller. So in this case, UI thread and background thread which submitted some work to UI thread, might work in parallel.

However, there is also `InvokeOnMainThread` which, as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/foundation.nsobject.invokeonmainthread), **waits** for the UI thread to execute the method, and does not return until the code pointed by action has completed. So in this case, background thread waits for UI thread to finish executing the given work, and then background thread continues execution.

Comment: InvokeOnMainThread - I had to use this in order to make sure, my API call gets executed and then I apply the changes to my UIImageView. Thanks for the explanation.