# Xamarin.Forms how display internet connection status?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

My HomePage is a CarouselPage and it contains three pages of type ContentPage.

```
<CarouselPage
    ...some namespaces...
    <CarouselPage.Children>
        <pages:HomePageA />
        <pages:HomePageB />
        <pages:HomePageC />
    </CarouselPage.Children>
</CarouselPage>
```

I'm using JamesMontemagno's ConnectivityPlugin to check if the device has internet connection:

```
  public partial class HomePage : CarouselPage
  {
    public HomePage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      if (IsConnectionAvailable())
      {
        // download content from external db to device (SQLite db)
        DisplayAlert("Internet connection found.", "Wait for the application data to update.", "OK");
      }
      else
      {
        DisplayAlert("No internet connection found.", "Application data may not be up to date. Connect to a working network.", "OK");
      }
    }

    public bool IsConnectionAvailable()
    {
      if (!CrossConnectivity.IsSupported)
        return false;

      bool isConnected = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;
      //return CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;
      return isConnected;
    }
  }
```

**After splash screen is gone, the message box doesn't show. Based on stepping through code while debugging I assume it kinda shows and then goes away before the splash screen disappears.**

So I tried to put the ConnectivityPlugin code into HomePageA:ContentPage, which one of the children of HomePage:CarouselPage. Like so:

```
public partial class HomePageA : ContentPage
  {
    public HomePageA()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      if (IsConnectionAvailable())
      {
        // download content from external db to device (SQLite db)
        DisplayAlert("Internet connection found.", "Wait for the application data to update.", "OK");
      }
      else
      {
        DisplayAlert("No internet connection found.", "Application data may not be up to date. Connect to a working network.", "OK");
      }
    }

    public bool IsConnectionAvailable()
    {
      if (!CrossConnectivity.IsSupported)
        return false;

      bool isConnected = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;
      //return CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;
      return isConnected;
    }

    private void RegistrationButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
```

Now when I run the application, the HomePageA gets displayed, but no message box. Only after I click the BurgerMenu and select Home (effectively selecting HomePageA) the message box pops up.


Same thing happens again:

**After splash screen is gone, the message box doesn't show. Based on stepping through code while debugging I assume it kinda shows and then goes away before the splash screen disappears.**


**Could somebody explain this behavior to me?


How do I make the message box appear AFTER the splash screen goes away?**

Thank you all.

===================== U P D A T E =====================

Pavan didn't explain the problem the way I would like to have it explained. For all you good people I found a couple of similar questions and answers with explanations that are adequate.


A decent explanation can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121760/what-is-device-begininvokeonmainthread-for) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206877/why-use-device-begininvokeonmainthread-in-a-xamarin-application)'s another one.

However, I will accept Pavan's answer, because it works and there has been no better answer provided at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DisplayAlert is used in order to do something on the UI thread. and it’s called from a background thread, in order to manipulate the UI, which can only be done on the UI thread.

Try below code for display alert message,

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Internet connection found.", "Wait for the application data to update.", "OK");
});
```

it will help you

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Where do I put that snippet? inside the 'if statement' ? Which class? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, put it in if and else.

Comment: I don't mean to pry, bro, but could you explain to me what exactly is happening when you force something to run on main UI thread? I'm googling for it as we speak, but I would also welcome your explanation.

Comment: @PaxForce, This is used in order to do something on the UI thread. So it’s normally called from a background thread, in order to manipulate the UI, which can only be done on the UI thread.

Comment: @PaxForce, I have also update my answer with above comment. I already explain your problem in my comments.